When taking sections of an existing c# codebase to create a module/package of code for general use, how should we configure the module?
When spinning off sections of a (C#) codebase to create libraries/package for use by other users within a team/organization, what are important considerations in terms of code & package configuration?
Additionally, when it comes to distribution and version control of these packages, is there a way to integrate the visual studio nuget/package interface? While keeping access to the packages controlled within a team/organization.


can you explain what problems you are having. how does the naive approach of "tick package as nuget and publish to a feed" fail you?

" is there a way to integrate the visual studio nuget/package interface? While keeping access to the packages controlled within a team/organization."  -- Yes, there's a section for this in the Microsoft docs.  You can just continue using the Visual Studio UI for any private NuGet feed in exactly the same way you're already doing in the above screenshot.   if you're having any difficulty using that UI with your own private feed then any questions for troubleshooting problems with tools belong on StackOverflow,

Can you describe what you mean by "package configuration?"
